# Windows Server 2019 and File Encoding

Tags: windows, utf-8

I have run into an issue with Windows Server 2019 with saving files as UTF-8 without a BOM.

If you create a simple file in Notepad on Windows Server 2019, and save it as .xml with UTF-8 (there is no BOM option at all, like on Windows 10/11 or older version of Windows Servers), it is actually saving with the BOM even though the option doesn't appear. I verified this by copying the file back to my laptop and opening in NotePad++ and I can see it has the BOM included.

Reason for needing no BOM is, I have to compile an .xml file in UTF-8 with no BOM. If it has the BOM, I cannot send it to who needs it, as it will break their import. I have put together a SSIS package to build the .xml file and I was actually stripping the BOM out with a script with no problems from my laptop, but when I load the same package into SQL and run from that 2019 server, it does not remove the BOM.

Has anyone run into this? If so, how do you get around the issue of not being able to save on Windows Server using a UTF-8 encoding without a BOM? I'm totally stumped...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a better text-editor than notepad.

An excellent one is the free [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/),
which has an option for encoding a file in UTF8 without the BOM.

Comment: Thanks but, I am trying to automate this process to keep others from having to open the file which could introduce other issues should they not be careful.

Comment: Based on the following thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260911/how-remove-the-bom%C3%AF-characters-from-a-utf-8-encoded-csv I can modify the BOM on Windows 10 just fine, but when i go to a WS2019, it puts the BOM back in, what am i missing?